# how to set/pass a $_POST field to a $_SESSION field?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database each user is set an access level of 1 or 2 that will show the user on dash.php certain content and restrict other content. I wanted to grab the $_POST['access'] data and set $_SESSION['access'] equal to it.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username AND password=md5($password)";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(!empty($num_rows)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$access = $_POST['access'];
}}
if ($result) {
$_SESSION['access'] = $access;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

Instead I'm getting array(2) { ["access"]=> NULL ["username"]=> string(4) "'user'". Could someone please explain to me how to do this? After this is working like it's supposed to I promise I'm going to convert the whole site to mysqli it's just that I'm learning and this just happened to be where I started out.

Comment: Please do not use MD5 or myqsl_* functions.. MD5 is broken. Has been for years, and mysql_* functions are depreciated and should not be used for new code, use MySQli or PDO as alternatives

Comment: Why are you allowing them to post the access?

Comment: I'm not allowing them to post the access, in this block I'm retrieving the access from post for the user from their row.

Comment: I didn't know that about MD5, is there an alternative I should use or will mysqli take care of that?

Comment: **DO NOT USE MD5 FOR HASHING PASSWORDS**. Read [the commandments](http://biasedphp.com/php-commandments), as you've broken several of them here. Right after you're done that, [read about SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you should not be writing SQL code that is published on the internet until you do. You will get into serious trouble if you're not aware of how to do this correctly. The consequences can be career destroying if a company's database gets leaked because of a mistake exactly like this.

Comment: xkcd and learning, you sir have made my day. How though should I go about trying the pass the value from my access field on my database to a session value?

Comment: If you're determined to do this the low-level way, 1990s style, [read a quick PDO tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A more enlightened approach is to spend some time familiarizing yourself with a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) that will make you significantly more productive since you can leverage a lot of pre-existing code instead of having to write every single thing yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you querying the database when you don't use the data?

The `$_POST` variable is populated [when data is posted to the script](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php) from a client (such as submitting a contact or signup form) and it has **nothing** to do with databases.

If you want to take the `access` field from the database and populate the `$_SESSION` variable, you need to change your database loop to:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $access = $row['access'];
    $username = $row['username'];
}}
```

While you're at it, you should be [escaping your query values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) when you insert data then [unescaping the data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) you retrieve from the database.

Comment: That makes so much sense! You are so very awesome thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. I'm going to go test it right now. I think you've already answered this perfectly though.

Comment: I was being stupid for a second and trying to echo $_SERVER['access'], you 100% answered my question. You have also answered a question about $_POST I didn't know how to ask. I don't have the reputation to upvote you but I sure wish I could. I can't tell you how awesome this is!!!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I helped. Once you understand these basics, programming becomes so much easier. Also don't forget: if you don't know anything, Google it, or ask here. Chances are what you want to know has already been answered (probably many times, too!).